# Why node-emoji won't print properly on nestjs/pino logger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs, emoji, pinojs

I am investigating a strange behavior from a Nestjs project I am developing, that wants to use @NestJs/Pino logger to display emojis in the terminal's logs. However, node-emoji only display the emoji properly in the terminal if I use `console.log(emoji.get('gear'))`. However, if I use `pino.info(emoji.get('gear') + ' test string.....')`, I get an output of: `[1646848210346] INFO (18320 on DESKTOP-2H3BS4O): **ΓÜÖ∩╕Å** test string.....`. Where "**ΓÜÖ∩╕Å**", is supposed to be the emoji printed by the logger at the terminal.

I have seek support at Nestjs's discord, but there, a user used my minimum reproduction repository, and the problem did not happened in their environment. I am using Windows/VSCode which leads me to believe that the problem might be something with my environment. So, here is the link to the repo:[link](https://github.com/pedroampucweb/generic-decorator), to run the project:

- npm i
- npm run start:dev
- Go to http://localhost:3000/api/#/default/AppController_getHello, and call the Get '/testEmoji'.
- Look at VSCode's terminal.

**MY VSCode Env**:

- Version: 1.62.3 (user setup)
- Commit: ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
- Date: 2021-11-17T08:11:14.551Z
- Electron: 13.5.2
- Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
- Node.js: 14.16.0
- V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

**My PC environment**:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- OS Version: 10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044

Information about package.json, package-lock.json, and confiuraton for @nestjs/pino logger can be found at the linked repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known limitation of Node.js that was [discovered by Pino back in 2018](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/issues/548). Pino team proposes this workaround in their [documentation](https://getpino.io/#/docs/help?id=unicode-and-windows-terminal).

Run this command in terminal:

`chcp 65001`

If you use nodemon and pino-pretty, you may have to add something like this to `package.json` to make it work in VSCode terminal (powershell by default).

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "chcp 65001 && nodemon index.js | pino-pretty"
  },
```

Then, running `npm run dev` will work.